# UIPickerView with 2 components

Tags: ios, ios4, ios5, uipickerview, uipicker

I have a UIPickerView with 2 components

The default value of both components is selected to the initial index.

How can I set the 1st component to the second index and leave the 2nd component on the 4th item.

-- UPDATE --

I added

```
[currencyPicker selectRow:1 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```

to

```
viewDidLoad
```

and now the elements in my UIPicker do not load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell it to go to a specific row, like this:

```
 [myPickerView selectRow:_my_row_ inComponent: _1st_component animated:YES];
```

Comment: I added this code to viewDidLoad and the elements in my UIPicker don't load. [currencyPicker selectRow:1 inComponent:0 animated:YES];

Comment: Put the selectRow call after you display the picker view.